# Prove for any a > b >0, b^n in Big-O a^n

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics, proof

> Prove that for any real numbers, a, b such that a > b > 0, b^n is O(a^n), n >=1.

I have searched several textbooks I own on Discrete Mathematics as well as several online searches for any examples that are similar or theorems that related to this proof.  I am not looking for a direct solution, but perhaps being shown the right methods or paradigms to solve the proof.

Comment: Homework? If so, thats fine, but please properly tag.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't this belong on the math  stack exchange site?

Comment: @Isthan -- actually, you use `ABS(b) / ABS(a) <= M` to choose M...so for x_0 = 1, `M = ABS(b) / ABS(a)`...now all you have to do is show that `b^x / a^x < 1 for all x > x_0` ...effectively you have to provide reasoning why `(b/a)^x is monotonically decreasing`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean

```
Prove that for any real numbers, a, b such that a > b > 0, b^n is O(a^n)
```

Then, think about the definition of `O(a^n)`

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation),

```
1) For f(x), g(x) defined on a subset of reals
2) if there exists some positive **constant** M and real number x_0, such that
3) if ABS(f(x)) <= M * ABS(g(x)) for all x > x_0
```

In this case `f(x) = b^x` and `g(x) = a^x`.  I'm going to treat this question as if it's a homework question, even though it isn't tagged as one...please correct me if I'm wrong!

Consider plugging the funciton into the steps (especially 3) and see if you can figure out **any** x_0, M pair for which it is true.  Good luck!

---

**EDIT**
I changed `f(x) = b^n` and `g(x) = a^n` to `f(x) = b^x` and `g(x) = a^x`

---

**EDIT - HINT**

Step 3) can be interpreted as:

```
ABS(f(x)) / ABS(g(x)) <= M for all x > x_0
```

Choose your favorite constant `M` and then see if you can find some `x_0` which works `for all x`.

Comment: @Isthan -- I have edited the post so that `n` becomes `x` when plugged into `f(x),g(x)`